# updated mccvim, now cannot source $HOME/.vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct 21 2017 01:21:26)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1207
```

My .vimrc has 
`:nmap ,s :source ~/.vimrc` I tried that right after installing the mccvim just now, and got these errors:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/jk/.vimrc:
line   18:
E15: Invalid expression: 0^M
line   20:
E15: Invalid expression: has("gui_running") && has("menu")^M
line   99:
E15: Invalid expression: 0^M
line  101:
E15: Invalid expression: has("gui_running") && has("menu")^M
line  203:
E15: Invalid expression: 0^M
line  205:
E15: Invalid expression: has("gui_running") && has("menu")^M
```

I don't find '0^M' in the .vimrc at all.

Everything was fine until the update; what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix-like systems (including OSX) and Windows have different conventions on what "end of line" should look like. Unix uses LF (ASCII `0A`, also represented as `^J`); Windows uses CRLF (ASCII `0D0A`, also represented as `^M^J`.

Vim can use both kinds of files, depending on its `fileformats` (`ffs`) setting. `set ffs=unix,dos` will make Vim try to guess how the file is formatted, and sets the `fileformat` (`ff`) accordingly. However, if `ffs` is set to just `unix`, then Vim will not try to guess, `ff` gets set to `unix`; under this setting, if the file was saved for Windows (i.e. has CRLF line endings), LF will be interpreted as newline, and CR will be presented as `^M`. Vimscript doesn't know what to do with `^M`, and complains.

To convert your file to Unix format (the recommended action, since your file is foreign to the operating system you're using), run these commands:

```
:e ++ff=dos .vimrc
:setl ff=unix
:w
```